# iOS in house install icon wont go away

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-house-distribution

My application installs perfectly i have put my ipa and plist online with this

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/ww/x/x.plist">
```

but when i install my application the install icon stay's on the springboard en the app goes right beside it but there is no possible way to delete the install icon.

i've tried restarting the ipad but doesn't work.
anyone else experienced this problem? and how to fix this? ( problem exists on ios6 and 7)

Comment: Check the device's console log (via the Organizer window in Xcode): it'll very likely contain some logging from `SpringBoard` or `backboardd` about what steps it took during installation, and what they thought of the download manifest.

Comment: Are the bundleID and provisioning id the same?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issue before. I've successfully uninstalled doing so:

1. Install the app via XCode (when device is plugged into your mac).
2. Install icon should disappear.
3. Uninstall the app directly from springboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall application, using iTuness. It  helped me when I have faced the same problem. Also  it indicates that your provisioning profile does not contain device UDID, or something else is incorrect in provisioning info.